# SQLite DB connection in R shows "file is not a database" in Raspi OS but works in Mac/Win

Tags: r, database, docker, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I am working on my side project that collects data from webscraping and generates the reports automatically.

I'd like to deploy the automation (just run the scripts with cronjob) on my raspberry pi. But I encounter a weird problem that doesn't show up on my Mac and Windows laptop.

## The issue

Long words short, when I open my sqlite3 file-based database in R, my Raspi gives me the following error message: "Error: file is not a database". However, my code works on my Mac and Win laptop. To be more specific, the following code behaves differently.

```
library(DBI)
conn <- dbConnect(drv = RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "database")
rawdata <- dbReadTable(conn, "db")
```

In Mac and Win, these 2 lines work perfectly. But on my Raspi (both Raspi OS and Ubuntu 20.10), they do not work.

## Reproduce the issue

I don't know what makes difference to SQLite on different OS (or to some other point I don't know), and here is the reproducible codes that may help:

1. Please find the file-based sqlite3 database [here](https://github.com/boyiechen/BerkeleyRSF_CrowdMeter/blob/main/database)
   For those who are interested in the creation of this sqlite file, it is created with [this python script](https://github.com/boyiechen/BerkeleyRSF_CrowdMeter/blob/main/main.py). It is basically [utilizing pandas method](https://github.com/boyiechen/BerkeleyRSF_CrowdMeter/blob/main/dbManager.py#L10-L16) `df.to_sql()` and write the scraped data into the file.
2. The data cleaning code can be found [here](https://github.com/boyiechen/BerkeleyRSF_CrowdMeter/blob/main/rshinyapp/data_cleaning.R#L22-L23), but you don't need to run all the lines because the main problem is not on the cleaning part, but on the right way to read sqlite3 database.

## My try

Also, I try to use the latest R version (4.2.2 2022-10-31) with the help of Docker to see if the issue is related to package versions. It seems like that Raspi still behaves differently compared to my Win laptop. (I did not try Docker on my Mac). Here is how I use Docker to reproduce my problem:

1. clone my side project
2. Pull the r-base image and create a container that mount the project folder

```bash
docker pull r-base
docker run -d -it --name renv -v /home/pi/repo/BerkeleyRSF_CrowdMeter:/home/repo r-base
```

3. Go to the shell of the container

```bash
docker exec -it renv sh
```

4. Run R and test reading the sqlite3 database

Still, Win side works perfectly and Raspi does not.

I try to search on questions about "Error: file is not a database", but the most related answers do not work. Some suggest give the file name extension back, but this does not solve the issue. Some say it is a question about old SQLite and SQLite3, but my limited knowledge about SQLite cannot help.

Any comment or suggestion is welcome! Thanks!

## Possibly helpful information

Here are the session info from my Win laptop and Raspi respectively:

```
# From Windows Side
PS C:\Users\boyie> R.exe

R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
Copyright (C) 2022 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> library(DBI)
> library(RSQLite)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_2.2.15 DBI_1.1.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.4      compiler_4.2.1 fastmap_1.1.0  cli_3.4.1      memoise_2.0.1
 [6] Rcpp_1.0.8.3   bit64_4.0.5    vctrs_0.5.1    cachem_1.0.6   blob_1.2.3
[11] rlang_1.0.6
```

```
# Raspberry Pi Side
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ R

R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

[Previously saved workspace restored]

> library(DBI)
> library(RSQLite)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RSQLite_2.2.19 DBI_1.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.5      compiler_4.0.3 fastmap_1.1.0  cli_3.4.1      pbdZMQ_0.3-5
 [6] memoise_2.0.0  Rcpp_1.0.9     bit64_4.0.5    vctrs_0.5.1    cachem_1.0.4
[11] blob_1.2.1     rlang_1.0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I still don't know the reason, I resolve this issue in a tricky way. It seems to be a file format issue, at least something deal with the file mode, storage option, or git-lfs. As I used `wget` to download `database` file directly instead of `git clone` the whole repo, I can open the file as a database.